# How do I find out if the first character of a string is a number in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string

How do I check to see if the first character of a string is a number in VB.NET?

I know that the Java way of doing it is:

```
char c = string.charAt(0);
isDigit = (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
```

But I'm unsure as to how to go about it for VB.NET.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As a sidenote, your first line could read simply: `char c = myString[0];`

Comment: @MatthewScharley - It can't in VB.BET

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a scratch program that gives you the answer, essentially the "IsNumeric" function:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim sValue As String = "1Abc"
    Dim sValueAsArray = sValue.ToCharArray()
    If IsNumeric(sValueAsArray(0)) Then
        Console.WriteLine("First character is numeric")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("First character is not numeric")
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: The call to ToCharArray is not necessary.  The first character of a string can be referenced by sValue(0).

Answer (score 7):

```
Public Function StartsWithDigit(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        Return (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) AndAlso Char.IsDigit(s(0))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function StartsWithDigit(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    Return s Like "#*"
End Function
```

Comment: it is very tricky but it works. Usable pattern are defined here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I will use 
*Dim bIsNumeric = IsNumeric(sValue.Substring(0,1))*
and not 
*Dim sValueAsArray = sValue.ToCharArray()*

It does not matter what you use, both will yield the same result, 
but having said that; *Dim sValueAsArray = sValue.ToCharArray()* will use more memory & *Dim bIsNumeric = IsNumeric(sValue.Substring(0,1))* will use less resources. though both of them are negligible

*It is more of a suggestion of programming practice than anything else.*

Comment: Hence me describing it as a scratch program. For an example I'll always forego error-checking and brevity for clarity and ensuring that the intent of the code is shown clearly

Answer (score 0):

```
Char.IsNumber(c)
```

More details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0):

The VB.Net code that is equivalent to your Java code can be done using following lines

```
Dim c = sText(0)
bIsDigit = (c >= "0" AndAlso c <= "9")
```

where

```
Dim bIsDigit As Boolean
Dim sText as String = "2 aeroplanes" 'example for test
```

But, there exist also other solutions

```
bIsDigit = Char.IsDigit(c)
bIsDigit = Char.IsNumber(c)
bIsDigit = Information.IsNumeric(c)
```

and when `sText` is an empty string, you can also use one of following lines

```
Dim c = Mid(sText, 1, 1)
Dim c = (sText & "-")(0)
Dim c = Strings.Left(sText, 1)
Dim c As Char = sText
```

But, for me, the best solution is

```
bIsDigit = Char.IsDigit(Mid(sText, 1, 1))
```

or

```
bIsDigit = Char.IsDigit(sText(0))
```

if you are sure that `sText` is not empty.

And the shorter (but tricky) solution is

```
bIsDigit = Char.IsDigit(sText)
```

In this last line, first character of `sText` is implicitely converted to `Char`.